# UNION not ouputting correct combined data in SQL/SSRS server 2008

Tags: sql, reporting-services, union

I am a NEWBIE, self taught SQL creator.
I have created a report that uses a series of queries to create 2 temp tables that need joined together.

When I run the report in SQL, I actually get the first temp table as a result, then I get the combined (UNION) result that I want as well.

Then, when I imported this SQL into SSRS and created the pretty report, I'm only getting the results of the FIRST temp table.  How do I correct this?  Here is the union statement that is supposed to combine the results of the two temp tables.

```
--declare @StartDate datetime
--declare @EndDate datetime
--declare @FirstGL nvarchar(9)
--declare @LastGL nvarchar(9)
--set @StartDate = '07-01-2014'
--set @EndDate = '02-01-2015'

--------------Temp Table #1 - Pulls invoice detail from AP for a selected time period and selected GL account numbers -------------------
select gl.acc_ext_id as [GL #]
       ,rtrim(gl.acc_ds) as [Account Descr]
   ,convert(varchar(10),ih.ivo_dt,101) as [Activity Date]
   ,((rtrim(vm.org_nm) + ' Inv#: ' + rtrim(ih.ivo_ext_id) + ' ' + (CASE WHEN ih.ivo_ds IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE rtrim(ih.ivo_ds) END) + (CASE WHEN id.ivo_dtl_ds IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE rtrim(id.ivo_dtl_ds) END))) as [Journal Descr]
  ,CAST(id.ivo_prc_at as decimal(12,2)) as [Inv Amt]

 into #APDetail

 from TAP600_INVOICE_HDR ih inner join TAP650_INVOICE_DTL id on id.ivo_int_id = ih.ivo_int_id
 inner join TAP300_VENDOR_MASTER vm on vm.vnd_int_id = ih.vnd_int_id
 inner join TGL910_CHART_OF_ACCOUNTS gl on gl.acc_int_id = id.acc_int_id

 where gl.acc_ext_id between @FirstGL and @LastGL
and ih.ivo_dt > @StartDate and ih.ivo_dt < @EndDate

 order by gl.acc_ext_id, ih.ivo_dt 

------------------Temp Table #2 - Takes temp table #APDetail and moves Inv Amt to either DR or CR field and limits length of description to 75 characters

 select distinct [GL #]
        , [Account Descr]
        , [Activity Date]
        , [Journal Descr] 
        , [Inv Amt]
 into #APDetailUpdate
 from #APDetail

 alter table #APDetailUpdate
 add Debit decimal(12,2)

 update apu

 set apu.Debit = ap.[Inv Amt]
 from #APDetailUpdate apu left join #APDetail ap on ap.[GL #] = apu.[GL #] and ap.[Account Descr] = apu.[Account Descr] and ap.[Activity Date] = apu.[Activity Date] and ap.[Journal Descr] = apu.[Journal Descr]

 where ap.[Inv Amt] > 0 or ap.[Inv Amt] = 0

 alter table #APDetailUpdate
 add Credit decimal(12,2)
 update apu
 set apu.Credit = ap.[Inv Amt]
 from #APDetailUpdate apu left join #APDetail ap on ap.[GL #] = apu.[GL #] and ap.[Account Descr] = apu.[Account Descr] and ap.[Activity Date] = apu.[Activity Date] and ap.[Journal Descr] = apu.[Journal Descr]
```

where ap.[Inv Amt]<0

```
 select [GL #]
 , [Account Descr]
 , [Activity Date]
 , [Journal Descr]
  --, [Inv Amt]
 , [Debit]
 , [Credit]

 from #APDetailUpdate

 order by [GL #], [Activity Date]

 --------------Temp Table #3 - Pulls journal entry detail from GL for a selected time period and selected GL account numbers---------------------

select gl.acc_ext_id as [GL #]
,rtrim(gl.acc_ds) as [Account Descr]
,convert(varchar(10),jh.jnl_pst_dt,101) as [Activity Date]
,(CASE WHEN jd.jnl_dtl_ds  IS NULL THEN jh.sys_cd + ' - ' + jh.src_ds ELSE jd.jnl_dtl_ds END) as [Journal Descr]
,sum((CASE WHEN jd.jnl_pst_deb_at IS NULL THEN '0.00' ELSE jd.jnl_pst_deb_at END)) as [Debit]
,sum((CASE WHEN jd.jnl_pst_crd_at IS NULL THEN '0.00' ELSE jd.jnl_pst_crd_at END)) as [Credit]

into #GLDetail  

from TGL220_JE_HDR jh inner join TGL250_JE_DTL jd on jd.jnl_int_id = jh.jnl_int_id
inner join TGL910_CHART_OF_ACCOUNTS gl on gl.acc_int_id = jd.acc_int_id

where gl.acc_ext_id between @FirstGL and @LastGL
and jh.jnl_pst_dt > @StartDate
and sys_cd <> 'AP'

 group by gl.acc_ext_id, gl.acc_ds, jh.jnl_pst_dt,(CASE WHEN jd.jnl_dtl_ds  IS NULL THEN jh.sys_cd + ' - ' + jh.src_ds ELSE jd.jnl_dtl_ds END) 

 order by gl.acc_ext_id, jh.jnl_pst_dt

 -----------------------Final Report - Combines the two tables with a Union statement --------------------

select [GL #], 
    [Account Descr], 
    [Activity Date], 
    substring([Journal Descr],1,75),
    (CASE WHEN apu.[Debit] IS NULL then 0.00 else apu.[Debit] END) as Debit, 
    (CASE WHEN apu.[Credit] IS NULL then 0.00 else apu.[Credit] END)as Credit

from #APDetailUpdate apu

UNION

select  [GL #], 
      [Account Descr], 
      [Activity Date], 
      substring([Journal Descr],1,75),
      (CASE WHEN [Debit] IS NULL then 0 else [Debit] END), (CASE WHEN [Credit] IS NULL then 0 else [Credit] END)

 from #GLDetail

 order by [GL #], [Activity Date]
```

Comment: Sorry - couldn't get it to format so it's more readable!!

Comment: Is this really the SQL you are using in SSRS or is there more you're not including here?

Comment: Could the tables be identical?

Comment: This is not the complete SQL - this is just the last stage.  Everything before that works and outputs what I expect it to output.  If it will be helpful, I can include that as well.

Comment: No the tables are not identical.  One is pulling invoice data and the other is pulling manual general ledger journal entries.

Comment: I have include the whole SQL now.  Thank you!

Comment: `UNION` will remove any duplicates within the unioned datasets. `UNION ALL` will simply combine the datasets, without affecting the values. See if this affects your resultset. Furthermore, do all the work in SSMS to validate the output *before* muddying the water in SSRS.

Comment: I updated it to UNION ALL in SQL - I'm still getting 2 output files in SQL.  The second output does contain all of the information I'm expecting - and it was doing this before the change as well.  The problem arises when I import into SSRS and run it - I only get the output from the "from #APDetailUpdate apu"  part of the UNION ALL instead of the combined #APDetailUpdate and #GLDetail.

Comment: I suggest you move ALL of this into a stored procedure (with parameters) and call the stored procedure

Comment: Nick.McDermai - I'm a total newbie, so I don't know how to do that.  But thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're running two select statements:

```
 select [GL #]
 , [Account Descr]
 , [Activity Date]
 , [Journal Descr]
  --, [Inv Amt]
 , [Debit]
 , [Credit]

 from #APDetailUpdate

 order by [GL #], [Activity Date]
```

and

```
select [GL #], 
    [Account Descr], 
    [Activity Date], 
    substring([Journal Descr],1,75),
    (CASE WHEN apu.[Debit] IS NULL then 0.00 else apu.[Debit] END) as Debit, 
    (CASE WHEN apu.[Credit] IS NULL then 0.00 else apu.[Credit] END)as Credit

from #APDetailUpdate apu

UNION

select  [GL #], 
      [Account Descr], 
      [Activity Date], 
      substring([Journal Descr],1,75),
      (CASE WHEN [Debit] IS NULL then 0 else [Debit] END), (CASE WHEN [Credit] IS NULL then 0 else [Credit] END)

 from #GLDetail

 order by [GL #], [Activity Date]
```

SSRS will only ever return the results of the first select to be used as a dataset. You need to choose which one you want to be displayed as the dataset and then run a separate query in another dataset for the other select. Either that or union them all or remove the first select statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Christian Barron - I commented out the first select clause - had only included it because the sample I was modeling had that as well - and now it works.  Thank you!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to have been of assistance :)
You can accept the answer if you're happy with it and you will get some reputation for doing so.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to figure out how to do just that - but must be blind!!

Comment: There is a guide here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers :)

Comment: Thanks Christian Barron - I accepted your answer and I appreciate your help!